# Spring Repository performance issues with recursive ORM Class

Tags: java, mysql, spring, recursion, mariadb

**My aim:**

I have the children on the lowest level (for exmaple skill id 10 and 12) in a list. Now, I want all parents (parent_id = null) for every child (in this case, parent 34) and save them in a list again. After all I want the path from the parent to each child (34-9-10 and 34-9-12). Later on I want to check on every skill on these paths (34, 9, 10, 12).

Finally, I have a collection of skills that illustrates the pathes from top to bottom.

**Situation**:

I am using MariaDB (MySQL Dialect) and have the following, recursive table (from idSkill: 9 to parent 34)

[image: recursive table]

Now I am asking for every parent element (parent_id = null) with Spring Crud Repository. To do so I am using a loop that is iterating over a list with all parent-element-ids and calling findOne(parentelementid) for every parent element id and using LAZY Loading:

```
List<Skill> parentList = skillDAO.findBySkill(null);
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> parentTree = customSkillDAO.findParentIdsByPersonSkills(listPersonskill);

    //Integer: Durchnummeriert zur Eindeutigkeit, von 0,1,2...
    //List: Pfad vom höchsten Vaterlement zum niedrigsten Personskill
    //Notwendig, um den Pfad pro niedrigsten Knoten auf true zu setzen
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> parentTree = customSkillDAO.findParentIdsByPersonSkills(listPersonskill);
    log.info("START FINDING CHECKED");
//keySet is just numbered from 0,1,2,3...
for (int counter : parentTree.keySet()) {
        //parentTree.get(counter) gives a list whith Integer that describes the path from top to bottom.
        //So the first element is always the parent.
        mapParentSkills.put(parentTree.get(counter).get(0), new SkillDTO(skillDAO.findOne(parentTree.get(counter).get(0))));
        mapParentSkills.get(parentTree.get(counter).get(0)).setChecked(true);
    }
    log.info("START FINDING NOT CHECKED");
//Add all other parent that are not checked
for (Skill skill : parentList) {
        if (!mapParentSkills.containsKey(skill.getIdSkill())) {
            mapParentSkills.put(skill.getIdSkill(), new SkillDTO(skill));
        }
    }

    log.info("ENDE SKILLS");
```

I am getting the whole tree wich is fine. The only issue is that it take about 10 seconds. **Can anyone tell me some suggestion to improve it to do it at least in <2 secs?**

Here is my class:

```
public class Skill implements java.io.Serializable {

    public Skill() {
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "idSkill", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdSkill() {
    return this.idSkill;
}

public void setIdSkill(Integer idSkill) {
    this.idSkill = idSkill;
}
```

...Some @JsonBackReferences, which are not loaded

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public Skill getSkill() {
    return this.skill;
}

public void setSkill(Skill skill) {
    this.skill = skill;
}

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "skill")
public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
    return this.skills;
}

public void setSkills(Set<Skill> skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}

}
```

LOG:

> web - 2016-02-13 16:53:50,163 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - START FINDING CHECKED
>   Hibernate: select levelbezei0_.idLevelBezeichnung as idLevelB1_4_0_, levelbezei0_.bezeichnung as bezeichn2_4_0_ from quanto_portal.levelBezeichnung levelbezei0_ where levelbezei0_.idLevelBezeichnung=?
>   Hibernate: select skills0_.parent_id as parent_i4_15_0_, skills0_.idSkill as idSkill1_15_0_, skills0_.idSkill as idSkill1_15_1_, skills0_.levelBezeichnung_id as levelBez3_15_1_, skills0_.name as name2_15_1_, skills0_.parent_id as parent_i4_15_1_ from quanto_portal.skill skills0_ where skills0_.parent_id=?

...Same select for ~50 times...

> web - 2016-02-13 16:53:51,523 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - START FINDING NOT CHECKED
>   Hibernate: select skills0_.parent_id as parent_i4_15_0_, skills0_.idSkill as idSkill1_15_0_, skills0_.idSkill as idSkill1_15_1_, skills0_.levelBezeichnung_id as levelBez3_15_1_, skills0_.name as name2_15_1_, skills0_.parent_id as parent_i4_15_1_ from quanto_portal.skill skills0_ where skills0_.parent_id=?

..Same select several hundred times...

> web - 2016-02-13 16:53:59,289 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - ENDE SKILLS

**UPDATED LOG**

> web - 2016-02-13 19:48:25,471 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - START FINDING CHECKED
>
> Hibernate: select levelbezei0_.idLevelBezeichnung as idLevelB1_4_0_, levelbezei0_.bezeichnung as bezeichn2_4_0_ from quanto_portal.levelBezeichnung levelbezei0_ where levelbezei0_.idLevelBezeichnung=?
>
> web - 2016-02-13 19:48:25,806 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - START FINDING NOT CHECKED
>
> web - 2016-02-13 19:48:25,807 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.s.controller.ProfileController -  - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - ENDE SKILLS

SKILLDTO:

```
public SkillDTO(Skill skill) {
    idSkill = skill.getIdSkill();
    name = skill.getName();
    levelBezeichnung = skill.getLevelBezeichnung().getBezeichnung();
    checked = skill.isChecked();
    if (skill.getSkills().size() > 0) {
        Iterator<Skill> iteratorSkill = skill.getSkills().iterator();
        while (iteratorSkill.hasNext()) {
            Skill tempSkill = iteratorSkill.next();
            skills.add(convertSkillsToProfileDTO(tempSkill));
        }
    }
}

private SkillDTO convertSkillsToProfileDTO(Skill skill) {
    return new SkillDTO(skill);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you "asking for every parent element" from repository?

Comment: I edited my question and added the code

Comment: Is field `levelBezeichnung` of `Skill` an entity?

Comment: Yep it is and marked with @JsonBackReference. I am using annotations on getter (property annotation?).

Comment: Seems cause of issue detected. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for one more try. You are not right, but also not wrong. Yes the time between loggings are shorter: (look updated Log), but for the first time I am loading the "parent skills" it takes a lot of time (see updated question). **I think the issue causes by a select statement for every child**.

Comment: I updated my question once more. Sorry, for my bad english, but I'm trying to explain what I am trying to do without giving too much unnecessary information.

Comment: I don't see the place where you use select statement for every child. Do you mean `findParentIdsByPersonSkills`? Possible, there is not optimal implementation.

Comment: I get the path from the root to the leaf with `findParentIdsByPersonSkills`. But actually these many sql statements are called by the first "findOne"

Comment: I counted the select statements: 176. So for every skill there is a select statement

Comment: You should attempt to reduce count of select statements. For example, try to get it with single request. As you see, when you working with big collection, query statements can become cause of performance issues.

Comment: I have no possibilies to reduce the select statements unless I write my own. The next problem is that MariaDB has no recursive function and this makes it even harder to get the tree with "simple select statement".
I also think about redesigning my skill-table. I read about difference aspects to have hierarchical data in relational database, but all have their advantages and disadvantages. I'm not sure which solution could be the best with the less workload.

Comment: @KenBekov another idea that came today: how about storing all skills in a bean during tomcat startup? So I dont need to do a query for every service.

Do you know how i can use "skillDAO.findByParent(null)" in bean? I mean the skillDAO is autowired during startup, too, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up loading skills in cache without redesigning my tables.

See:
[Spring boot preloading data from database in bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427728/spring-boot-preloading-data-from-database-in-bean)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, because provided code is not enough to understand what your application does.

But possible process takes long time, because you send too much requests in the loop. Separate requests usually takes more time, than single one. Try to replace it with single request. For example:

```
@Repository
public interface skillDAO extends CrudRepository<Skill, Integer>{

   ...

   @Query("select s from Skill s where s.skill is null")
   List<Person> findRootSkills();
}
```

and use it as:

```
List<Skill> rootSkillList = skillDAO.findRootSkills();
for(Skill skill : rootSkillList){
        SkillDTO dto = new SkillDTO(skill)
        dto.setChecked(true);
        mapParentSkills.put(skill.getIdSkill(), dto);   
}
```

---

If you need to get skills by Ids exactly from you `parentTree` structure, you can do next:

```
@Repository
public interface skillDAO extends CrudRepository<Skill, Integer>{

   ...

   @Query("select s from Skill s where s.idSkill in (:idList)")
   List<Person> findSkillsById(@Param("idList") List<Integer> idList);
}
```

now just collect all Ids from your `parentTree` and get list of `Skill` objects:

```
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int counter : parentTree.keySet()) {
    idList.add(parentTree.get(counter).get(0));
}
List<Skill> rootSkillList = skillDAO.findSkillsById(idList);

//here you can fill mapParentSkills
```

I'm not sure, did I detected point of time delay right. Possible, delay is in DTO's method - `setChecked(true)`. But anyway hope this will be useful.

**UPDATE:**

```
public SkillDTO(Skill skill) {
    ...
    //LOOKS LIKE NEXT LINE IS YOU PROBLEM
    if (skill.getSkills().size() > 0) {            
        Iterator<Skill> iteratorSkill = skill.getSkills().iterator();
        while (iteratorSkill.hasNext()) {
            Skill tempSkill = iteratorSkill.next();
            skills.add(convertSkillsToProfileDTO(tempSkill));
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like, I found cause of performance issue. In you `Skill` class field `skills` declared as:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "skill")
public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
    return this.skills;
}
```

`fetch = FetchType.LAZY` means, that `Set` will be loaded just when you invoke method `getSkills()`. So every time you invoke method `getSkills()`, JPA creates and sends query to DB for fetch list of skills. And constructor does it for EVERY skill in list of skills. It takes a lot of time. Try to replace `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, and I suspect, performance will increase a much.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, but I need to tell you that i apparently showed the wrong code extract. Nevertheless, I think that I will use your code later because it seems to be more readable.
I extended my code once more.

There you can see that I started logging: From "START FINDING CHECKED" to "START FINDING NOT CHECKED" it takes ~1s. Thats fine...
From "START FINDING NOT CHECKED" to "ENDE SKILLS"  nearly ~9s are gone.
I added the log to my question.

Comment: @Andy what `SkillDTO` doing? Possible, there is some long process in class constructor?

Comment: it added the SkillDTO constructor and convertToSkillDTO-Method. I am using this recursion and constructor to convert all parent children's to SkillDTO. This may could be time intensive, but I don't know how to do it in another way.